# True or false? $A \cap( C - B) \subseteq (A \triangle B) \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \cap( C - B) \subseteq (A \triangle B) \cap C$

I tried some sets and I got something that works for example $A=\{1,2,4,5\}$ , $B = \{2,3,5,6\}$ and $C = \{4,5,6,7\}$
so we get that $( A \triangle B) \cap C = \{4,6\}$
and $A \cap (C-B) = \{4\}$ so the statement can be true

I tried proving this way:

let $x \in A \cap (C-B) $ then we have $x \in A \land x \in C \land x \not \in B$

also tried some identities for the other side $(A \triangle B) \cap C =\iff (A \cup B)-(A \cap B) \cap C \iff ((A \cup B) \cap (\overline A \cup  \overline B)) \cap C \iff ((A-B) \cup (B - A)) \cap C \iff ((A -B) \cap C) \cup ((B -A) \cap C)$

so we have $x \in A \land x \not \in B \land x \in C \lor x \in B \land X \not \in A \land x \ \in C$

but I do not know how to continue from here or even if that helps

thanks for any tips and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRUE. Use the fact that "$\land$" statements are associative: $(X \land Y) \land Z$ and $X \land (Y \land Z)$ are equivalent.

$$x \in A \cap (C-B) \implies (x \in A) \land ((x \in C) \land (x \not \in B))$$
$$ \implies ((x \in A) \land (x \not \in B)) \land (x \in C) \implies x \in (A \Delta B) \cap C.$$

This gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $x\in A\cap (C-B)$ implies that $x$ is in $A$ and $C$ and not in $B$. Since $x\in A-B$, $x\in A\Delta B$. Since $x$ is also in $C$, $x\in (A \Delta B)\cap C$. So any $x\in A\cap (C-B)$ is also in $(A\Delta B)\cap C$, and $A\cap (C-B)\subseteq(A\Delta B)\cap C$.